# Lumen FatalThrowableError on validation

Tags: php, validation, fatal-error, lumen

I've been struggling with this for a while now.
Here's the code I've got.

> ```
> public function store(Request $request)
> {
>     $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
>         'name' => 'required|max:100'
>     ]);
>     if ($validator->fails()) {
>         //do something
>     }
> }
> ```

The problem is that I get a FatalThrowableError right in my face with the following message:

> Call to a member function parameter() on array

I can't find what I'm doing wrong. I'd appreciate some help here. 
And also, I've had this validation before which worked:

```
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|unique:developers|max:100'
    ]);
```

But the thing with this one is, I had no idea how to catch when the validation failed. Is it possible to catch the validation fail when using it this way?

Using version: "laravel/lumen-framework": "5.2.*"

Comment: What version of Lumen are you using?

Comment: "laravel/lumen-framework": "5.2.*"

Comment: My answer below was for 5.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `FatalThrowableError` exception is low level exception that is thrown typically by the symfony debug `ErrorHandler`. In lumen the queue worker, PhpEngine, console kernel and routing pipeline uses it as well.

Make sure of the following

1. That you have copied `.env.example` to `.env`
2. If you are using Facades, make sure that you enabled it inside `bootstrap/app.php` by uncommenting the line.

`$app->withFacades();`

Inside Lumen 5.2.8 either of the following would work.

The following will actually return a valid JSON object with the errors. You did not elaborate on your use case why that is not sufficient. What is nice with using the `validate` call like this is it actually returns a `422` http status code, which implies an unprocessed entity.

```php
$app->get('/', function (Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required'
    ]);
});
```

Using the facade works as well, albeit is returns a `200` status code.

```php
$app->get('/', function (Request $request) {        
    $validator = Validator::make($request->only(['name']), [
        'name' => 'required'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return ['error' => 'Something went wrong'];
    }
});
```

If you still do not come right with the `Validator::make` you can catch the default Validation exception using. It feels a little hacky.

```php
$app->get('/', function (Request $request) {
    try {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required'
        ]);
    } catch (\Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException $e) {
        // do whatever else you need todo for your use case
        return ['error' => 'We caught the exception'];
    }
});
```

Comment: The .env file and facades were in place, no problem there. Then I tried your second example with the $validator->fails() which worked. One thing I noticed is it was exactly the same as mine but with one difference and that was that you take 1 request variable only. So I get the error on $request->all(). I really wonder why that can't be done? And one more question, in your example the validation is in the routing, I've got mine in my controller, is that an issue?

Comment: That is strange, $request->all() and $request->only(['name', 'surname']) will both return arrays. However, $request->all() uses array_replace_recursive and combines input with files uploaded. Then there will be no difference in moving the validation to the controller, it will use the same Request object.